# Accessing Keberized Hadoop cluster programmatically

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos

We are trying to access the kerberized Hadoop cluster(Cloudera distribution) using code(java) but getting the below exception.

> Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain
>   password from user at
>   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897)
>   at
>   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5Login
>   Module.java:760) at
>   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)

We have used the property "hadoop.security.authentication" as `kerberos`,`fs.defaultFS` as  `hdfs://devha:8020` and passed the keytabfilepath in the userinformationgroup.

Comment: The error message hints that the Hadoop auth lib was bypassed, and the base JAAS library was called instead. Looks like you did not initialize properly the static `UserGroupInformation` object, or some rogue Java property prevents it to init properly. Have fun with your next 4 weeks of debugging...

Comment: Must read : _Hadoop and Kerberos, the Madness beyond the Gate_ -- especially the debug flags in _Low-level secrets_ section

Answer (score 0):

First, read the comments on your question. Good stuff.

Taking a step back since that information can be overwhelming there's two possible ways to authenticate to a Hadoop cluster. A *user* will normally use a username (principal) and password. An *application* will normally use a principal and a keytab file. A keytab file is created by the Kerberos administrator using the 'kadmin' application.

Furthermore there's the concept of a "Login" user - an application wide default, or a "Current" user that could be specific to your current need. You'll often use the former to access resources on your local cluster and the latter to access resources on an external cluster.

Since I'm using the latter I can give you a quick code snippet to get you started. For initialization:

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration);

where "configuration" is either read from the standard location (/etc/hadoop) or generated on the fly. Note - that sets a static value so you need to be very careful!

For the individual user (application) I use

```
UserGroupApplication user = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, keytabFile);
```

there are several variants of this method - e.g., do they take username or keytab file? Do they set the "Login" user or do they return a new UserGroupInformation object? Be careful you understand the consequences of which one you're using since some set global values.

You now have to wrap your calls to the cluster in a doAs() call:

```
user.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
    public Void run() throws Exception {
        // do all of your hadoop calls here
        return null;
    }
}
```

I don't recall if you need to do this if you're always using the "Login" user. We need to support both local and external clusters and for us it's easiest to always wrap everything like this. It means we only need to set "user" once, at the start of the action.

See the resources mentioned above if you want details on user impersonation, using SSL encryption (rpc.privacy), etc.

Comment: Nit : AFAIK the `loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI` is only useful if you need multiple Kerberos creds _in parallel_. Otherwise you just need to initialize the **static** UGI object with `loginUserFromKeytab` ... then skip the `doAs` annoying stuff

Comment: True. I often forget that we have a pathological use case (multi-tenant hosting) and that forces us to take extra steps that most sites don't need to worry about. We actually need to support both forms since the customer can self-host (and thus handle everything via /etc/hadoop) or they can use our multi-tenant hosting (if they just need access to a third party cluster),... or they can self-host and still need access to third-party clusters with different authenication. Happy happy joy joy!